# Why does my MainStoryboard not appear in the Base localization list?

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I'm using xcode 4.5.2 and iOS 6.0, but why is my MainStoryboard file dose not appear in the Base localization list?

[image: Why is my MainStoryboard dose not appear in the Base localization list?]

Answer (score 4):

You need to select your storyboard, then in the first tab of the attributes inspector, select Localize and it'll add it to your localisations.

Comment: I know, but I want to create Base localization, this's Xcode 4.5 new feature.

Comment: Base localization isn't supported yet for iOS apps.

Comment: there http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/InternationalizeYourApp/InternationalizeYourApp/InternationalizeYourApp.html

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Xcode release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW145), they state:

> The Use Base Internationalization setting in the project editor works
>   only on Mac products for deployment on OS X v.10.8 and later. Xcode
>   must also be running on OS X v.10.8 or later. This setting is not
>   supported on iOS projects. 11712855

Comment: I'm create new iOS 6.0 project on OSX 10.8.2 with XCode 4.5.2 can use this.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same thing with some of the projects in my workspace.

Answer's in Apple's docs:

> If no resources appear in the dialog, add your .storyboard and .xib
>   files to a language, as described in Adding Additional Resources to
>   Language Folders, and repeat these steps.

**Developer Documentation:**
[Internationalization and Localization Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingYourUserInterface/InternationalizingYourUserInterface.html)